# Standard ML : recursive function with two arguments

Tags: recursion, sml

I'm doing a practice problem and I'm stuck.

I'm supposed to declare a function `sum: int * int -> int` where

> sum(m,n) = (m+(n-1))+(m+n)

My recursive function is as follows:

> `sum(m,0)= 0 
>            | sum(m,n) = m+sum(n-1)+(m+n);`

Why do I get an error?

Comment: but `sum(m,n) = (m+(n-1))+(m+n)` isn't a recursive function at all -- are you sure that the goal isn't to sum all numbers in the range n to m?

Comment: That might be... however it is under the chapter of recursion... ? Maybe they want a recursive function for the sum of all numbers?

Comment: The problem is that what you wrote is algebraically equivalent to `sum(m,n) = 2m+2n-1` which doesn't really make sense. It *is* a standard exercise (important in some axiomatic treatments of the natural numbers) to define addition recursively from the successor function, but that would correspond to `sum(m,n) = sum(m,n-1) + 1`. Are you sure that you copied it down correctly?

Comment: @JohnColeman  that makes sense.... (what you wrote) It's from the book Introduction to Programming using SML from Michael R. Hansen & Hans Rischel. I double checked - they do write it like I wrote above. Maybe it's a typo in the book?

Comment: I learned SML from that book (and liked it very much). I just checked my copy. In the Chapter 1 exercises, problem 1.4 asks you to define the function `sum(m,n) = m + (m+1) + (m+2) + ... + (m + (n-1)) + (m + n)`, which makes a lot more sense. It seems like the copy you are using somehow allowed a typo to creep in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this is really supposed to do, but you're getting an error because the recursive call in the second line has only one argument, though `sum` needs two.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that too just now. I have something like this now: `fun sum(m,0)=1 | sum(m,n) = m+sum(m,~1);` which does give me an output of `val sum = fn: int* int -> int` but I don't really think this is correct. Any idea?

Comment: @opheliaxo: Update your question with this information.